GRUB password seems useless, so why even bother?
My system has full disk encryption except for /boot. I've set a GRUB password by following this post, but then was able to disable it by booting into Kali Live and running:
mkdir /mnt/dev/sda2
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/dev/sda2
sudo vim /mnt/dev/sda2/grub/grub.cfg

3 commands. Easy peasy.
A user will only see the GRUB menu or be asked to enter a GRUB password if they have physical access to the machine (right?). If they have physical access, they can disable GRUB. If a user doesn't have access to GRUB (ie they connect via ssh or this is a VM (because ssh only starts after GRUB finishes, right?)), then they'll never be stopped by it.
So it seems like in the only situation that a GRUB password is used, it is also easily bypassed. If a GRUB password ever stops someone, they can disable it.
So, what's the point? Is GRUB passwords as useless as I think? Do they increase security in any other way? What if we throw /boot encryption into the mix? Does that improve things?
Thank you!

By that logic, why use any passwords at all? After all, one can simply move the disk from one computer to another and access anything as root. User or bootloader passwords in general are not designed to stop data access, encryption is designed to do that.
GRUB passwords are not about restricting data access or modification from a booted machine. Instead, they are useful as part of a wider system of locking down a computer. For example, you can set up BIOS/UEFI passwords to prevent booting from unauthorised devices and restrict physical access to the machine. GRUB passwords add an extra layer of protection by preventing unauthorised users from modifying the boot parameters or selecting different boot entries. They are not designed to act as a wholesale method of securing a machine.
In a real, locked down scenario, you would not only have a GRUB password, but would have restrictions on (for example) booting untrusted or unattested devices. In these scenarios bootloader passwords can present an actual benefit.

You're right, physical access defeats both GRUB and OS passwords (unsure of what to call them, but the credentials used to log in with ssh). I see a difference in that OS passwords are used both for remote and physical access, whereas GRUB passwords are only seen when the user has physical access.
So the OS passwords have a situation in where they are used but the physical access hacks can't be used (logging in remotely), but GRUB passwords don't. GRUB is only relevant when you have physical access, and is defeated by the same. GRUB seems useless in this way. Where am I wrong? Thanks!

Consider a scenario where a system is protected with both a BIOS/UEFI password and a GRUB password. The BIOS/UEFI password prevents booting from unauthorised devices. Even if an intruder has physical access, they can't boot from a live USB without the BIOS/UEFI password. The GRUB password then adds another layer by preventing unauthorised changes to boot parameters or the selection of alternate boot entries through GRUB, ensuring the system starts only with the intended configuration. All security is just layering.

It makes a lot more sense when combined with a BIOS/UEFI password! Thank you!
